# Calling button click from another button click

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to press RoutedEventArgs e button (button in page) from EventArgs e button (button on application bar) in windows phone 7

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button0_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void button0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

when i am using above code its giving me

cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs'

Please Help

SMS CODE:

```
    SmsComposeTask SCT = new SmsComposeTask();

    PhoneApplicationService PAS = PhoneApplicationService.Current;

    public string SMSNO;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        object sample;
        if (PAS.State.TryGetValue("numbertext", out sample))
            SMSNO = sample as string;
        if (PAS.State.TryGetValue("messagetext", out sample))
            txtOutput.Text = sample as string;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOutput.Text != "")
        {
            SCT.To = SMSNO;
            SCT.Body = txtOutput.Text;
            SCT.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Output is Empty to send SMS.", "Wait!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        PAS.State["numbertext"] = SMSNO;
        PAS.State["messagetext"] = txtOutput.Text;
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the parameter inside button0_Click, you can just call button0_Click(sender, null);  (the reason is that the event from the application bar don't bubble that's why they don't have a RoutedEventArg parameter)

Comment: ok its working... the thing is i wanted to send sms from application & when i enter this code in normal button its opening messaging app but if i am putting this code behind application bar its not working but same way i am sending email from application bar button so why its not working for sms?

Comment: it looks like opening messaging app needs to be done using routedeventargs

Comment: no I don't see how this could be related to routed args (there no visible diference between an button with RoutedArg or without), could you share the code you are using to open SMS? I almost sure it because of an error somewhere else (maybe you put the event handler on the wrong app button?)

Comment: I don't see any pb and just to be sure tried to put the SMS launch from an app bar button and it was working..

Comment: Is it doing an error when you do it? and if you put a breakpoint in your click function is it called?

Comment: The only other thing i see is that you are using textbox so there is one thing which is different when you press an app bar button is that the textbox don;t lose focus (you can just set the focus on the page if needed)

Comment: no there is no error it just dont run from application bar button even if i click on it 4 5 times

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37558/discussion-between-xsheru-and-benoit-catherinet)